# Android listview show layout in setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

i use baseadapter to show some items in listview.in my baseadapter's layout file i have one RelativeLayout and i want show hide this layout in listview's click.i wrote some code witch can show/hide layout but it is not enough.at the moment this layout show is possible every item's click,but i want.for example if i click second item and second item's layout is show and then if i click 3th item,3th  items layout would show and second's items layout must hide.
at the moment i can show both layout,but i want to show only one layout every time

[this is a picture my baseadapter layout file](http://postimg.org/image/ywq76lqft/)

first time this black layout is hidden
how i can solve my problem

this is a my code

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {
            holder = (UserHolder) view.getTag();


            if (holder.layout.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {


                holder.layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            else
            {
                holder.layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }









        }

    });
```

how i can change code witch would can show this layout only one each items click ?
if anyone knows solution help me 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

in XMl set Relative layout visible,

and in getView method of base adapter,while adding the view of initial child make it visible,rest of child's invisible